# Energy estimate for nonlinear term

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parameter-estimation, nonlinear-analysis, parabolic-pde

Let $ \Omega$ be open and bounded. Consider that $u$ is smooth solution of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=(u\cdot \nabla)u~~~in~\Omega\times[0,T]\\
u=0~on~~~\partial \Omega\times[0,T]\\ 
u(\cdot,0)=0~in~\Omega.
\end{equation}

Notice that $u$ is not divergence-free. After testing with $u$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{2dt}||u||_2^2=\int_\Omega (u\cdot \nabla)u\cdot u~dx
\end{equation}
I have a problem due to convective term. I want to get an estimate on which one can apply Gronwall lemma.

Comment: As it stands, I have no clue what sort of estimate you want, so please add more information to your question. Is $u$ divergence free? that makes things very easy

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am sorry, I add more information.

Comment: There's a 1D version here which gets you a $H^k$ estimate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536114/basic-burgers-equation-energy-estimate/3536524#3536524 maybe you can adapt this to higher dimensions.